# Execute several ODC (Power Query) and store output file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, power-query

This may be an X/Y problem. Everyday reports are uploaded on an external SharePoint I have access to.

Everyday, I have to manually download the reports, work on them and save as new updated individual reports with date as timestamp, and then create a global report that will be based on those.

I managed to automatize the '*work on them*' part with Power Query. However, everyday I still have to:

- Copy/paste the new report files with the new timestamp (for each reports)
- Open them and update the query
- Save
- Copy/paste the new global report
- Open it and update the query

It is both annoying and something that should be automatically done. I know I can export the different query as ODC file and I wonder if there's a way to execute those in a predefined order and save the output files in a predefined path (with timestamp)

I'm new to SharePoint (he'ce the possible X/Y issue) so I don't know the feature available. I don't think we can use Flow. I don't have Power BI, just Excel.